# NavigationController and Modal Views

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, modal-dialog

I am a newbie to iOS world and have started building custom code on top of a templated code.
So excuse me for the obvious.

The View chain starts with a `MainWindow.xib` which contains a App Delegate Object, a Window Object and Application ViewController. I dont understand why those objects are needed over there. But what I understand, I need to mention starting ViewController in the `"Nib Name"` Property to initiate my custom View Controller (called "EmptyViewController"). Its a dummy view controller, just there to avoid crash to happen as a result of missing valid viewcontroller.

I initiate a separate Modal View Controller(`MainViewController`) inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. 
*Code for initiating modal View Controller --*

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
mainView = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
// present the viewcontroller
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainView];

[self.viewController presentModalViewController:navController animated:NO];

// release it, because it's retained as modalViewController
[navController release];
```

I do not put this MainViewController inside `MainWindow.xib` as I want to have navigation at the root of MainViewController.
Inside `MainViewController`, I push HelpViewController when "help" button is pressed.
But HelpViewController does not show any navigation bar. I do not understand why?

*Code for Pushing Navigation bar --*

```
HelpViewController *helpVC = [[HelpViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:helpVC animated:YES];
[helpVC release];
```

So I would like to understand --
1) Why is MainWindow.xib needed? Can I remove it? (Note: I tried to remove it, but then I get blank screen)
1.a) Why are all the controls/objects App Delegate Object, a Window Object and Application ViewController objects needed?

2) Why doesnt HelpViewController show Navigation bar?
3) Another thing I noticed, if I say self.presentingViewController, EmptyViewController handle is returned while popViewController returns me back to MainViewController.

Thanks

Comment: If my answer helped you Vselect and ^plus it please.

Comment: @meaning-matters your answer answered what I already knew. Was looking at more precise answer.

Answer (score 0):

The App Delegate simply implements some app-level 'callbacks' by which iOS communicates with your own code.  In main.m you can see how iOS is told which of your classes implements `UIApplicationDelegate`.  iOS creates an instance of this class and call these delegate methods ('callback') whenever appropriate (e.g. when the app goes to background).

The Window is something iOS provides, your app needs to tell what to display on it.  And, as you saw, this is usually done in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` (which is called by iOS to inform your app things are ready to get started).

A View Controller is a class that handles states of stuff you show on the Window.  You don't show stuff directly on the Window, but instead use Views.  Every View Controller has a View with UI elements.

The XIB or NIB is a UI description/layout file.  A XIB and View are linked together; you need to tell the XIB to which View Controller member (e.g. a `UILabel`) a UI element belongs, and you tell the XIB which View Controller method to call on a certain UI event (e.g. user taps on a button).

These are the basics.  I'm aware it does not answer all your questions; I suggest you read the very good Apple documentation.  Don't try to understand everything immediately as things, as you're experiencing, indeed can seem illogical at start.